# how to duplicate textview in the same linearlayout dynamically?

Tags: android, textview

[My question seems same like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798826/duplicate-views-on-android-during-run-time)
I've created a layout file with linearlayout and a textview inside it.Need to generate duplicate textviews of a textview with different texts in the same linearlayout dynamically(programmatically). Can anyone suggest the correct answer.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Isn't a for loop working?

Comment: You can't duplicate a view, you have to create a new textview and add it dynamically.

Comment: for looping is working fine. But, i need the duplicate of textview which is in the xml layout, exactly in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically create a `TextView` in code and add it to some container view.  Another approach might be to use layout for TextView and do something like following (this scales better if individual elements get more complex and also easier to use layout to populate various attributes of TextView)

```
for (some loop) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.text_view_layout, null);
    containerView.addView(textView);
}
```

`containerView` would be  your `LinearLayout` that you get using `findViewById`

Comment: what if I've linearlayout inside a scrollview?

Comment: that makes no difference....you can still use `findViewById` to get the `LinearLayout` you're interested in

Answer (score 0):

now that I understand, I hope everyone can

my main -> activity_duplicate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".DuplicateViews">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar_layout_duplicate">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout_duplicate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/duplicate_views" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my include -> duplicate_views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DuplicateViews"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_duplicate">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llContainer_duplicate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20dip">
        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

my layout to be duplicated -> layout_to_be_duplicated.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="tv_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the class -> DuplicateViews.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.duplicate_views.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_to_be_duplicated.view.*
class DuplicateViews : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var arrayOfText: Array<String>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duplicate)
        arrayOfText = arrayOf(
            "text one",
            "text two",
            "text three",
            "text four"
        )
        for (i in arrayOfText.indices){
            val duplicateThis = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_be_duplicated, null) as RelativeLayout
            llContainer_duplicate.addView(duplicateThis)
            duplicateThis.tv_text.text = arrayOfText[i]
        }
    }
}
```